# Alternative way to use goto statement

Tags: c, goto

I am confused about writing a program that takes '/' character from user and warning to user not to use 0 in numerator. I have build the program but I want an alternative method to using the `goto` statement.

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char o;
    int num1,num2;
    printf("Enter one operator like '+' '-' '/' '%%' '*' : ");
    scanf("%c",&o);
    printf("Enter 1st number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
my: printf("Enter 2nd number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num2);
```

Below I want to remove these 2 lines but it should achieve the same result as it works.

```
    if(o=='/' && num2==0 ){
        printf("You can't divide by zero \n");
        goto my;
    }    
    switch(o) {
        case '+':
            printf("%d + %d = %d",num1, num2, num1+num2);
            break;
        case '-':
            printf("%d - %d = %d",num1, num2, num1-num2);
            break;
        case '*':
            printf("%d * %d = %d",num1, num2, num1*num2);
            break;
        case '/':
            printf("%d / %d = %d",num1, num2, num1/num2);
            break;
        case '%':
            printf("%d %% %d = %d",num1, num2, num1%num2);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Operator is not correct");
            break;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    system ("pause");
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't remove the code and make the answers look meaningless

Comment: See [Goto still considered harmful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful/) for a discussion of the pros and cons of `goto` statements in general.

Comment: You should test the return valueof `scanf` to avoid undefined behavior and endless loop on EOF.

Comment: Be aware that 0 is not the only value that will cause a division overflow: `INT_MIN / -1` will produce an exception and crash your program.  Try typing `-2147483648` and `-1` as inputs.

Comment: You only test for zero division, but the modulo operator `%` has the same problem.

Answer (score 8):

> *There is nothing wrong with `goto` in and of itself!*

This is what most people fail to understand, instead simply parroting a poorly chosen snippet from a paper given decades ago, one that Dijkstra himself later came to regret, stating something along the lines of having "a bad feeling that people are making a religion out of it".

If people would simply try to *understand* the reasons behind guidelines like use of `goto`, `break` and `continue`, or limiting exit points from functions, and so on, they'd be far better practitioners of the art.

What Dijkstra *actually* railed against, and what I agree with whole-heartedly, was the "unbridled use of the go to statement", in a computing environment where there was mostly little else in terms of iteration. The fact that many environments *only* had `goto` could lead to a lot of spaghetti code, very hard to follow.

I actually consider blind dogmatism in the industry far more of a problem than `goto` statements ever were :-) The problem with `goto` is its *misuse,* since, as mentioned, it can make code much harder to follow and what I tend to do when I hear these pronouncements is ask:

> Is *this* code hard to follow or maintain because it breaks the "rules"?

If you were to restructure your code as follows:

```
// ===================================================
// Get the second number, disallowing zero if dividing.
getSecondNum:
    printf ("Enter 2nd number: ");
    scanf ("%d", &num2);
    if ((o == '/') && (num2 == 0)) {
        printf ("You can't divide by zero \n");
        goto getSecondNum;
    }
// ===================================================
```

you would be hard-pressed trying to come up with a `do` or `while` based solution that was *more* readable or understandable. You may *match* the readability but you'll often find that a poorly selected choice between the zero-or-more `do` and one-or-more `while` can render the code *less* readable.

For what it's worth, this is about as close as I can get to the same code in a non-`goto`-using way:

```
// ===================================================
// Get the second number, disallowing zero if dividing.
do {
    printf ("Enter 2nd number: ");
    scanf ("%d", &num2);
    if ((o == '/') && (num2 == 0)) {
        printf ("You can't divide by zero \n");
} while ((o == '/') && (num2 == 0));
// ===================================================
```

but that has other issues such as code duplication. That too can be fixed but it generally involves the use of more variables, or the use of `break` which has *exactly* the same issue as `goto` here<sup>(b)</sup>.

---

So, bottom line, *don't* take as gospel something you don't understand, it doesn't matter whether it comes from Dijkstra, Knuth, dkr, or even whatever other gods you may believe in :-)

Think about *why* it may be considered gospel in the first place, then *that's* how you decide whether it applies in a given situation<sup>(a)</sup>.

I *frequently* use `goto` in state machines, error handling and so on, places where it actually *simplifies* the code that would otherwise be harder to understand.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This includes advice from random people on the net, even from those called "paxdiablo" :-)

---

<sup>(b)</sup> One thing you *might* want to consider is to let the user enter zero even for a division, and then just sort it out in the calculation with something like:

```
case '/':
    if (num2 == 0)
        printf ("%d / 0 is undefined, cannot divide by zero", num1);
    else
        printf ("%d / %d = %d", num1, num2, num1 / num2);
    break;
```

I'd probably prefer the catch-early option myself but this *may* be a viable solution for you.

Comment: i also write the same code in floating point numbers, where floating point number is not reasonable with '==' sing. what i should do there? @paxdiablo

Comment: @Zainab, comparing floating point numbers is a totally different question, one that's been asked many times here on SO. Basically, you check for "close enough" rather than equal, such as if the difference is less than 0.00001% of the average, depending on all sorts of things. I'd suggest searching SO for the questions already asked on that topic.

Comment: i have searched about floating point number, and approximately got the point. Now, using do while loop in integer variables, if i enter 0.50 in num2, loop doesn't break. What should i do there? Why it does not pick the real number before the decimal point?

Comment: @Zainab, again this has nothing to do with _this_ question, you should ask another so that you get more people than just me looking at it. In this case, if you enter 0.50, you'll scan the int 0 and be left with the pointer looking at `.`. The next time you go to scan an int, it will be invalid because of the `.`. This will go on forever.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple alternatives check out mine.

```
while(1)
{
   printf("Enter a number\n");
   if(scanf("%d",&num2) == 1)
   {
     if(o == '/' && num2 == 0)
     {
       printf("You can't divide by zero\n");
     }
     else
     break;
   }
}
```

Comment: and if i using floating point numbers, then how can i restrict with comparing floating point number with '==' sign?

Comment: Remove the `continue` statement. It isn't needed here.

Comment: @CoolGuy You are right.. I don't see any reason why it should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into a loop like below:

```
do {
    printf("Enter 2nd number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num2);
    if(o=='/' && num2==0 ){
        printf("You can't divide by zero \n");
        continue;
    } else {
        break;
    }
} while (1);
```

Comment: i also write the same code in floating point numbers, where floating point number is not reasonable with '==' sing. what i should do there? @SMA

Comment: if that's the case you might need to look at [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/)

Comment: if i enter 0.50 in num2, loop didn't break. What should i do there?

Comment: your num2 is integer and not float type so dont pass float value.